# Can I call a function to solve for different variables?

Tags: octave

I have a function where I want to solve for many variables separately, do I have to write down the function every time in terms of the other variable?

```
x,xG,xR

y = e.^tan(x.^2)+cos.^2(x);
yG = e.^tan(xG.^2)+cos.^2(xG);
```

Comment: Your functions y(x) and yG(xG) are identical. There's just different names for the variables. Names are irrelevant.

Comment: I know the functions are identical, but how can I call a function to solve for any variable without just writing the whole thing again. if things got complicated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `x` and `xG` are the same variable in those two functions. They serve the same purpose and do exactly the same thing. They just have different names. But they are the same.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I get the impresion he's basically asking how to write a function

Answer (score 2):

First you cannot write an expression like cos.^2(x). If x is a single variable (ie x=pi) you could write either cos(x)^2 or cos(x^2).  If x is a vector (a column vector might be x=[3;4;pi] and a row vector might be x=[3,4,pi], then you might write cos(x).^2 or cos(x.^2). The role of the period (.) in octave is explained here: https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.3/Arithmetic-Ops.html

Another issue has to do with understanding the difference between an expression: x=e^tanh(y); and a function.  The later is a separate chunk of code that can be invoked from anywhere in your program.

Consider this simple example

```
1;

function y=myfunc(x)
  y=exp(tanh(x));
endfunction

## main program
xxx=pi/3;
yyy=myfunc(xxx);
printf('%7.3f %7.3f\n',xxx,yyy)
y=exp(tanh(pi/3))
```

comments:  The '1' in the first line tells Octave that there is more to the script than just the following function: the main program has to be interpreted as well.  The function line specifies that inside the function, the input will be called x and the output y, so when my function is called from main, the input is xxx(=pi/2) and the output is yyy.  The last line in this tiny script is an expression that does the same thing as the function. Note that since I didn't include a semi-colon at the end of that line the result is printed out

I suggest you play with this for a while, then if  you have more questions, ask them in a new question.